# use this inside function definition in a object don't work

Tags: javascript, this

Hi i'm trying to get the refence to the attribute name in that declaration but when i print `this.name` inside  fun attribute (function definition), of my object it doesn't work, instead when i use `this.name` in `this.img` attribute, it works.

why?

here's my code

```
    var submenu = new function(){

        this.name =  museum[i].name,
        this.title = 'It will merge row',

        this.img =img/this.name + '.png', //it work

        this.fun =  function (data) {
            console.log(this.name); //it doesn't work
        }
  };
```

it prints undeclared....

Comment: are you sure that this `this.img =img/this.name + '.png', //it work` works as is or it is a typo?

Comment: How exactly are you calling `this.fun`? What is the behavior you see? You should definitely not use the comma operator here. Use semicolons to terminate he assignments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try storing the scoped this into a variable

```
var submenu = new function(){
    var that = this;
    that.name =  museum[i].name,
    that.title = 'It will merge row',

    that.img ="img/"+that.name + '.png', //it work



     that.fun =  function (data) {
               console.log(that.name); //it doesn't work

     }
 };
```

### EDIT

This error happens because "this" is a scoped keyword and a little change in the scope will affect the keyword content. So, you store the keyword in the scope you want to work and use the variable instead.

Answer (score 2):

Because the `this` keywords [has some funny behaviours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127440/1167210), and it changes depending on how you call your functions!

```
var submenu = new function(){
  var self = this;
  //in here, `this` refers to the `submenu` function
  self.name =  museum[i].name;
  self.title = 'It will merge row';
  self.img = 'img/'+ self.name + '.png';

  self.fun =  function (data) {
    console.log(self.name);
    //but in here `this` refers to the `fun` function
  }
};
```

Comment: great it works !!! beautiful...

Answer (score 0):

Every function invocation has both a [scope and a context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) associated with it. Context is always the value of the `this` keyword which is a reference to the object that “owns” the currently executing code. try assingning the context of your submenu fuction to a variable and use that variable in the inner function

```
var submenu = new function(){
var that = this;
that.name =  museum[i].name,
that.title = 'It will merge row',

that.img ="img/"+that.name + '.png',

that.fun =  function (data) {
           console.log(that.name); 

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the `this.name` var inside the `this.fun` function! Please create a local copy as bellow

```
   var submenu = new function(){

    this.name =  museum[i].name,
    this.title = 'It will merge row',

    this.img ='img/'+this.name + '.png', //it work

   var clone=this;

     this.fun =  function (data) {
               console.log(clone.name); //it doesn't work

      }
 };
```

Comment: But why does the OP not "have" `this.name` inside the function?

Answer (score 0):

Write your object and use prototyping:

```
var submenu = function(){
    this.name =  museum[i].name;
    this.title = 'It will merge row';
    this.img ='img/' + this.name + '.png';
};
submenu.prototype.fun =  function (data) {
   console.log(this.name); 
};
```

Comment: How exactly does this solve the problem?

Comment: It's true that this works, but then again, so would `submenu.func()`, which would be a much simpler solution since it doesn't require changes to the code the OP posted. The OP's code already works if called correctly. The issue is that they are not calling it correctly. All you do is restructure the code but the issue will stay the same.